# How do I get specific column data

Tags: java

```
List<List<Object>> EventAll = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
List<Object> row = new ArrayList<Object>();
while(rs1.next()) {
   EventAll.add(rs1.getRow(), row);
}
```

Instead of getting all the columns I want to get only two columns data.

Comment: could explain better?

Comment: what is rs1? a resultset ? where and how did you get it ? what do you mean by specific column ? what is EventAll ? what does thes EventAll.add method do ? details please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `rs1` is `java.sql.ResultSet`, to get data of particular column, you can use `rs1.getString(columnNum)`, in the case when the data type is string. Below is an example:

```
    int columnIndex1 = 1;
    int columnIndex2 = 4;
    while(rs1.next()) {
        List<Object> row = new ArrayList<Object>();
        row.add(rs1.getString(columnIndex1)); // get one column
        row.add(rs1.getString(columnIndex2)); // get the other column
        EventAll.add(row);
    }
```